# Pyspark: write to csv writes parquet instead of csv

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In the code below, out.csv is in parquet format. What option am I missing for it to write it as a csv file?

```
import py4j
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark import HiveContext as hc
import os
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row

from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType,StringType
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.5.0'
conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local[64]").setAppName("My App")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

#read parquet file into DF
df = sqlContext.read.parquet('/path/in_parquet')

# Write to csv
df_grouped = df.groupBy('column1').agg(F.sum('column2'))
df_grouped.repartition(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("/path/out.csv")
```

**Output:**

the last few lines remaining in the console. also, here is the command i used to run the script:

spark-submit --master local[*] --driver-memory 12g --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.2.0  MyPyspark.py

```
$ hdfs dfs -ls /path/out.csv
Found 2 items
-rw-r--r--   3 me devs          0 2017-06-29 12:16 /path/out.csv/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   3 me devs        552 2017-06-29 12:16 /path/out.csv/part-00000
```

Comment: Can you show a piece of the output ?

Comment: edited the question to add output log and more info.

Comment: The file output, not the job :-|

Comment: Sorry. Just added the file output.

Comment: That's a CSV formatted file written with Hadoop MultipleOutputFormatFile... that's not a parquet file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark is saving each partition of the data separately, hence, you get a file `part-xxxxx` for each partition. The path you specify `.save("/path/out.csv")` is the directory to save the files to, the `part-xxxxx` files in there are already in `csv` format.

If you have multiple files and a small dataset you can use `coalesce(1)` and then save the result to recive a single `csv` file. For larger datasets, I would recommend first saving and then merging the files with `FileUtil.copyMerge()` (Hadoop command).